# How to reset "wm size" changes from recovery or unlock android phone with graphic key via keyboard/mouse?

Tags: recovery-mode, external-keyboard, oneplus-7-pro

After entering wm size 1920x1080 in terminal I was unable to reset this setting.

Now I have TWRP running and no information about how wm store its parameters in memory. Using adb is not possible (for adb shell wm size reset) as I cannot unlock phone (nor with usb keyboard nor with usb mouse)

So the quiestion is: how to reset changes of wm command or unlock a phone with usb keyboard or mouse (graphical key)?

Comment: Adb commands don't need the lock screen to be unlocked to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. Type in console:

> wm size reset